# How to disable cache for specific file?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, layout, cache

I want to disable cache for a specific file which I am loading with a layout file. Is this possible?

I tried it like this, because I saw it like this somewhere:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>konfigurator/konfigurator.js</script>
        <lifetime>null</lifetime>
    </action>
</reference>
```

But it does not work? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="block.name">
    <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
    <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: How does this work in my case?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do , disable a js cache via layout ? if yes why ?

Comment: yes. Because I am developing a javascript file and I always have to wait 2 minutes before I can see the changes.